# Is it possible to start Daphne in a python script without using an OS call

Tags: python, django, django-channels, daphne

Is it possible to run a daphne process or even just Django channels from a python script?

The recommended way to do it, is to run

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 django_project.asgi:channel_layer
```

I was wondering if I could bind that to a variable and run it the way Tornado could

```
from tornado.web import Application
application = Application([(r"/", RosbridgeWebSocket), (r"", RosbridgeWebSocket)])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a work around, but you may use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) module like this:

`subprocess.run(["daphne", "-b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 django_project.asgi:channel_layer"])`

Check this thread [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more info on the use of subprocess module.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I can call it as a subprocess, but then unless I write a bunch of IPC code this wouldn't work

Comment: Have you considered creating a .sh bash script calling daphne as you would normally do from command line and call that script from the subprocess?

Comment: That's the current way this works. I'd ideally have it as a python object though

Comment: In the subprocess documentation, states that it returns a CompletedProcess instance, so it is an object...

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Django Channels but have you tried using inmemory or redis Channels directly? You might be able to avoid daphne altogether. From what I understand, daphne seems to be the protocol translator layer so outside clients can communicate with Django through daphne (Django uses wsgi rather than asgi so Django alone cannot handle certain protocols, such as, websocket communication). Tornado does not rely on wsgi.

There are examples in daphne tests:
https://github.com/django/daphne/blob/master/daphne/tests/test_http.py

The inmemory ChannelLayer is not cross-process. I'm not sure if that even matters in your use case. If it does, you can check the other backends (such as redis channels) https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/backends.html

This might be more directly what you are looking for:
https://github.com/django/asgi_redis

Comment: I just started reading about this last night. Indeed this looks like the object that I have to customize to run other python code with my Daphne. Still looking into it but here's hoping

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it swap the tornado to NGINX ?

http://masnun.rocks/2016/11/02/deploying-django-channels-using-daphne/

Comment: Um, how would that help? Plus I'm not using Tornado, I'm using Django Channels

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue...

```
from daphne.cli import CommandLineInterface
CommandLineInterface().run(('my.asgi', '--bind', ip_address, '--port', '8000'))
```

Should do the trick. The trouble is that I don't see this documented anywhere and so the API may not be very stable.

This is the same code route as calling Daphne through subprocess:
https://github.com/django/daphne/blob/main/daphne/cli.py#L167
https://github.com/django/daphne/blob/main/daphne/cli.py#L204